# What is is the difference between these two codes?

Tags: java, swing

This code right here is a button of a calculator that is when pressed shows "2" in the calculator's textbox
I was just curious why the first code allows me to enter number "2" just once

while the second one allows me to enter the number "2" Many times, in other words, what does `textbox.getText()` adds to this code?

```
private void BUT2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    String enternumber =  BUT2.getText();
    textbox.setText(enternumber);
}
```

```
private void BUT2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    String enternumber = textbox.getText() +BUT2.getText();
    textbox.setText(enternumber);
}
```

Comment: What do you think is the difference? Walk through the code mentally and you should see it.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Thank You, I Will surely learn these naming conventions

Comment: My first comment was much more important than the second since to solve similar problems in the future, you will absolutely need to learn to do mental walk-throughs of your code, asking yourself "does this code make sense?" and "what is this code currently doing?" as you walk through it -- also known as "[Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)". Also, in the future, tell your thoughts on the code, why you think that one code is doing one thing and the other is doing something different. Your question quality would benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet copies the label of the button (`"2"`) into the text field, replacing its prior content.

The second snippet looks at what's already in the text field, which could be anything, and adds the label of the button (`"2"`) to the end of it.  This way, you can add `"2"` to the text field as many times as you press the button.